# How to migrate Global term store from SharePoint 2013 to SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, powershell, csom, term-store

We are migrating Global term store from SharePoint 2013 to SharePoint Online. Can i get the scripts to download the term store and then upload that in SharePoint Online? We want to upload/download using CSOM script.

Comment: Hi Adarsh, did you got the answer? Can you share with us?

Comment: Also I have asked similar question here, can you please answer there, https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/255169/how-to-migrate-managed-metadata-columns-from-2013-onprem-to-sharepoint-online

Answer (score 0):

There is an article about [How to Migrate SharePoint Taxonomy Term Stores from SharePoint 2013 On-premise to On-premise or On-premise to Online](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1099878/Migrate-SharePoint-Taxonomy-Term-Stores-from-Share).

It use PowerShell scripts to export and import term stores, check if it’s feasible for you.