# How to migrate Managed Metadata columns from 2013 OnPrem to SharePoint Online

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, migration, managed-metadata-service

We have taxonomy columns maintained on Manage Metadata service on SharePoint 2013 On-premises which are used by different lists. Now we are planning to move this sites on SharePoint online. My questions are:

1. How we will migrate managed metadata columns on SharePoint Online?
2. When I will migrate lists, will they able to connect to this migrated columns on SharePoint online or i will loose the values in these columns?

Comment: @P S for migration we are using Sharegate, so tool will take care of local term store, but for global term store we need to export/import term store.

Comment: Thanks Adarsh, will you able to tell me about my second question? In case of global term store, when I will migrate from On Prem to Online will lists which already has managed metadata columns will able to get values form term store of Sharepoint online? Or there will be data loss?

Comment: Sorry for late response @P S. Yes after migration SP online lists will get values from term store as it is. No data loss will be there.

Comment: Thanks Adarsh, can you please tell me how you migrated global term store? Any link for reference?

Comment: you can use any tool like sharegate,metalogix or use powershell that is there in below URL:  https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1099878/%2FArticles%2F1099878%2FMigrate-SharePoint-Taxonomy-Term-Stores-from-Share

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We migrated global term store using ShareGate tool. The mapping remain same and there was no data loss.

Answer (score 0):

There is a CMDlet especially designed for your use case: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/copy-sptaxonomygroups?view=sharepoint-ps

I used the CMDlet during the SharePoint hybrid configurations. It worked well if you use a onmicrosoft-Account instead of a synced one.

The IDs will be copied as well. 
The mappings should stay in place since the IDs are the same.